# Why DOMDocument() works in several URLs and in others not?

Tags: php, rss, domdocument

im using this simple script to parse RSS data:

```
<?php

//PUBLIC VARS
$arrFeeds = array();
$downItems = 0;
//*PUBLIC VARS

function getRSS($source) {
    global $arrFeeds, $downItems;
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load($source);
    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $itemRSS = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue
        );
        array_push($arrFeeds, $itemRSS);
        $downItems+=1;
        //echo($arrFeeds[$TT]['title']."<br>");
    }
}
getRSS("http://www.atm-mi.it/_layouts/atm/apps/PublishingRSS.aspx?web=388a6572-890f-4e0f-a3c7-a3dd463f7252&c=News%20Infomobilita");
echo(strip_tags($arrFeeds[1]['title'])."<br><br>".$arrFeeds[1]['desc']);
?>
```

This script works great with almost any rss you try, but with this particular one: http://www.atm-mi.it/_layouts/atm/apps/PublishingRSS.aspx?web=388a6572-890f-4e0f-a3c7-a3dd463f7252&c=News%20Infomobilita it wont work, and the rss is valid, so im thinking that is maybe a security issue, any way, how can i solve this and make my script more realiable? Thanks!

Comment: What does "it won't work" mean? Are there any errors? What do you get?

Comment: i get a "Time out", try a test of the script.

Comment: if `->load()` fails, it returns FALSE. You should check for that, at minimum, before proceeding with the rest of the dom operations. Never EVER assume an external resource will work perfectly all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by changing the value of ["`default_socket_timeout`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout) using [`ini_set`](https://www.php.net/ini_set). The problem appears to be the that the server is trying to keep the connection alive.

```
$url = 'http://www.atm-mi.it/_layouts/atm/apps/PublishingRSS.aspx?web=388a6572-890f-4e0f-a3c7-a3dd463f7252&c=News%20Infomobilita';

ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 1);

$dom_document = new DOMDocument;
$dom_document->load($url);
```

Alternatively, you could consider using [cURL](https://www.php.net/curl) which is much more flexible.

```
$url = 'http://www.atm-mi.it/_layouts/atm/apps/PublishingRSS.aspx?web=388a6572-890f-4e0f-a3c7-a3dd463f7252&c=News%20Infomobilita';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$dom_document = new DOMDocument;
$dom_document->loadXml(curl_exec($ch));

curl_close($ch);
```